# Emulate iPhone contact list header style in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of system alerts with dates and times associated with them.  Dates only show when there is a change in date.  What I would like is for the topmost date to stick at the top of `#shell` until another one displaces it.  This is very similar to how the contacts app works on the iPhone.

I have [setup a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjajt/2/) that has everything in it bar the necessary jQuery code. If anyone could help me out here I'd be very grateful - I currently have no idea where to start!

Snippet of HTML:

```
<div id="shell">
    <div id="alertList">
        <div id="alert_0" class="alert">
            <span class="date">22 Nov, 2012</span>
            <span class="time">02:28</span>
            System alert happened
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code

```
$("#shell").scroll(function() {
    //This is where the code would be to lock (or alter the margin-top) of the
    //date would be in order to keep it locked to the top
});​
```

Comment: The code you need is for moving the date after an alert is inserted?

Comment: I know I need to subscribe to the `scroll` function but literally have no idea what to do next

Comment: I'm not following you. You want that the first date keep at the top of shell instead of hiding "above" because of the scroll?

Comment: I want to keep the date that just passed at the top, such that the current date is always shown as you scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late but sure: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/sjajt/17/)

```
$("#shell").scroll(function() {
    // 21 is because of border and padding.
    var firstVisible = parseInt($("#shell").scrollTop() / ($("#shell .alert:first").height() + 21)),
        firstVisibleElem = $("#shell .alert:eq(" + firstVisible + ")"),
        date = firstVisibleElem.data("date");

    if (date != undefined && date != null && date > -1)
        $("#date_" + date).prependTo(firstVisibleElem);
});

// Save the date corresponding to each alert:
var i = -1;
$("#shell .alert").each(function() {
    var date = $(this).find(".date");
    if (date.length > 0) {
        i++;
        date.attr("id", "date_" + i);
    }
    if (i > -1) {
        $(this).data("date", i);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Chris, you can also play a little with firstVisible instead of truncating and make it look a little nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code ... It still needs a bit of work and refactoring, but i hope you get the ideea. (Here's the link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjajt/18/) too)

```
var currentElemIndex = 0;
var currentElem = $('#alertList .date:eq(' + currentElemIndex + ')');
var currentElemMarginTop = parseInt(currentElem.css('margin-top'));
var currentElemHeight = currentElem.outerHeight();
var currentElemPosTop = currentElem.position().top;
var nextElem = $('#alertList .date:eq(' + currentElemIndex+1 + ')');
$('#shell').scroll(function (ev) {
    var scrollTop = $('#shell').scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop >= nextElem.position().top - currentElemHeight) {
        currentElemIndex++;
        currentElem.css('margin-top', currentElemMarginTop + 'px');
        currentElem = nextElem;
        currentElemMarginTop = parseInt(currentElem.css('margin-top'));
        currentElemHeight = currentElem.outerHeight();
        currentElemPosTop = currentElem.position().top;
        nextElem = $('#alertList .date:eq(' + currentElemIndex + ')');
    }
    if (scrollTop  > currentElem.position().top) {
        currentElem.css('margin-top', $('#shell').scrollTop() - currentElem.position().top + 'px');
    }
    if (scrollTop < currentElemPosTop) {
        nextElem = currentElem;
        currentElemIndex--;
        currentElem = $('#alertList .date:eq(' + currentElemIndex + ')');
    }
});
```